# catch a string in boolean option

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming, boolean, case

How do I prevent error when someone does not choose one of the options in scala. This is using Map to get options and I tried to implement Try and catch blocks in case options but it does not work. I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, if there is any other way let me know. The error is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "e".

```
object main extends menu {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var opt = 0
    do { opt = readOption }
    while (menu(opt))
  }
}   

class menu extends database {
  def menu(option: Int): Boolean = try {
    actionMap.get(option) match {
      case Some(a) => a()
      case None => println("That didn't work.")
      false
    }
  } catch {
  case _: NumberFormatException => true
  }
  val actionMap = Map[Int, () => Boolean](1 -> cWords, 2 -> cCharacters, 3 -> exit)

def readOption: Int = {
    println(
      """|Please select one of the following:
         |  1 - Count Words
         |  2 - Count Characters in words
         |  3 - quit""".stripMargin)
    StdIn.readInt()
}
```

Comment: First you need to have a `Boolean` as result in the `case NumberFormatException`

Comment: and then replace `case NumberFormatException` with `case _: NumberFormatException`. And what exactly would throw this exception?

Comment: A simple `actionMap contains option` doesn't work out for you?

Comment: he doesn't need to check if map contains key, he already does this using `Map.get` that returns `Option`. The code that causes problems is probably not present in this question.

Comment: @Łukasz I changed the result of `case NumberFormatException` to boolean value and as you suggested replaced the number format exception. The problem might be with `StdIn.readInt()` which I use at the end of `readOption` function. that is used by the main class. Should I add the code that is working with this function? tak wogole dzieki :)

Comment: can you post the answer in the answer section so if it works I can submit it as answered

Answer (score 1):

Use `scala.util.Try` on `readInt()`,

```
import scala.io._
import scala.util._

Try(StdIn.readInt()).toOption
// returns Some(123) for input 123

Try(StdIn.readInt()).toOption
// returns None for input 1a3
```

Thus `readOption` delivers `Option[Int]`. Then

```
def menu(option: Option[Int]): Boolean = option match {
  case Some(a) => actionMap(a)()
  case None    => println("Try again..."); false
}
```

*Note*

A more concise version of `main`,

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = while (menu(readOption)) ()
```

Namely, while `menu` is `true` do `Unit` (or `()` ).

Comment: Do I need to put value to the `Try(StdIn.readInt()).toOption
Some(123)  // input 123` because if I do `Some` it does not work, as program demands a value like 1 but If I put that the value in, it will be defined before user can choose any option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working implementation:

```
import scala.io.StdIn
import scala.util.Try

object Main extends Menu with App {
    while (menu(readChoice)) ()
}

class Menu {
  val actionMap = Map[Int, () => Boolean](1 -> (() => true), 2 -> (() => true), 3 -> (() => false))

  def menu(choice: Option[Int]): Boolean = {
    choice.flatMap(actionMap.get)
      .map(action => action())
      .getOrElse({ println("That didn't work."); false })
  }

  def readChoice: Option[Int] = {
    println(
      """|Please select one of the following:
         |  1 - Count Words
         |  2 - Count Characters in words
         |  3 - quit""".stripMargin)
    Try(StdIn.readInt).toOption
  }
}
```

For the first, you can mixin App trait to skip `main` method boilerplate.

You can simplify your `do while` loop like this, it has to do nothing inside so you either need some expression or block. A `Unit` value can be your expression that does nothing.

In scala we name classes using camel case, starting with capital letter.

As `readInt` throws whenever input is wrong you can catch that using `Try`, that will return `Success(result)` of `Failure(exception)` and change this result to an `Option` to discard the exception.

what happens in menu is shorthand for

```
choice match {
  case Some(number) =>
    actionMap.get(number) match {
      case Some(action) =>
        action()
      case None =>
        println("That didn't work.")
        false
    }
  case None =>
    println("That didn't work.")
    false
}
```

And could be as well written with `for`

```
(for {
  number <- choice
  action <- actionMap.get(number)
} yield {
  action()
}) getOrElse {
  println("That didn't work.")
  false
}
```

On as sidenote, you named choice of user an "option" which unfortunately is also a scala class used here extensively, I renamed the variables to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would make `readOption` return a `Try[Int]`, (a `Try` surrounding `StdIn.readInt()`), then deal with the possible cases in the `menu` function